# How to make the title sections in a tcolorbox raster the same height?

Tags: tcolorbox, box, raster

I am using the tcolorbox raster to display a couple of boxes.

One of my boxes has a longer title which breaks into a second line.

How can I make it that the red title on the left has the same title as the green title on the right?

(In the MWE you can see that I tried to use option `adjust text` but apparently that is wrong.)

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={Pellentesque interdum sapien},adjust text={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege},left=1mm, colbacktitle=red]  
            \lipsum[75]
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege},adjust text={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege}, colbacktitle=green,left=1mm]
            \lipsum[66]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image: tcolorbox example of a raster with unequally high titles]

Comment: try with deleting `left=1mm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your titles as `boxed titles` with option `attach boxed title to top*` and apply an `equal group height` as `title style`.

i think that `adjusted title` is only valid for one line titles. In this case it compensates the existence different height and depths, but it doesn't work for two or more line titles.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={Pellentesque interdum sapien},adjust text={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege},left=1mm, colbacktitle=red]  
            \lipsum[75]
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege},adjust text={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege}, colbacktitle=green, left=1mm]
            \lipsum[66]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
    
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height]
        \begin{tcolorbox}[skin=enhanced, title={Pellentesque interdum sapien}, attach boxed title to top*, left=1mm, colbacktitle=red, boxed title style={equal height group=A}]  
            \lipsum[75]
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[skin=enhanced, title={Nunc sed pede. Praesent neque justo vehicula ege},attach boxed title to top*, colbacktitle=green, left=1mm, boxed title style={equal height group=A}]
            \lipsum[66]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! A note, if you have standard colors like me the filled title stops to work so you have to add `colbacktitle=black!75!white` to make it look filled.